# Getting table of contents to recognize titlesec paragraph

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, titlesec

I am using `hyperref` to make a clickable table of contents.

I am using `titlesec` to use `\paragraph{ }` as if it were a `subsubsubsection`. How do i get this use of `\paragraph` to display in my table of contents  (`\tableofcontents`)? Currently it is not displaying. Note that I also what this to be a clickable table of contents and I use `hyperref` to do so, as is demonstrated below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{FooBar}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{ 
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{titlesec} %paragraph as subsubsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{TestSection}

\subsection{TestSubSection}

\subsubsection{TestSubSubSection}

\paragraph{TestSubSubSubSection}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You have to issue the command `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The depth of sectioning in the toc is controlled by `tocdepth`

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

would send `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` to the toc.

Comment: Wasn't this in my comment already?

Comment: @karlkoeller sorry, your comment wasn't there when I landed on the page:-)

Comment: It doesn't matter, David. I leave you this tick for one of those I've stolen to you in the past ;-)